# Joining new columns in MySQL One-To-Many

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot

I asked a similar question the other day but it seems no one was able to answer it, and searched the internet for a few days but still fruitless, perhaps I am not asking the question the right way:   [One-to-many Query in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444718/one-to-many-query-in-mysql)
So I while try again and maybe word it a bit differently. This is essentially a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(  
customer_id INT NOT NULL,  
first_name varchar(20),  
last_name varchar(20)  
);  
CREATE TABLE Payment(  
customer_id INT NOT NULL,  
amount_paid INT,  
year YEAR,  
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES Customer(customer_id)  
);
```

What I want is to organize the first_name on the left, only occurring once, and then for each year list the payment amount in separate columns because I am going to be attaching this to WPF and I want a spreadsheet style representation of the data. So, ideally it would look like this:

```
name 2009 2008 2007  
John 500 600 NULL  
Anne NULL 500 600  
Bob NULL NULL 600
```

My approach is to count the number of distinct years of payments, and use that as a loop counter. than loop through and collect the data for each year. Represent each column of amount_paid by the year number. I am not just not sure how to do that, because my initial approach was to use UNION, but than I realized that just puts everything in the same column as opposed to separate ones. So what should I be using? I am only asking for some guidance. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT c.first_name,
         MAX(CASE WHEN p.year = 2009 THEN c.amount_paid ELSE NULL END) AS 2009,
         MAX(CASE WHEN p.year = 2008 THEN c.amount_paid ELSE NULL END) AS 2008,
         MAX(CASE WHEN p.year = 2007 THEN c.amount_paid ELSE NULL END) AS 2007
    FROM CUSTOMER c
    JOIN PAYMENT p ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY c.first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql unfortunately has no `pivot` feature, so the only possible way is to format the result set with any programming language.

Comment: Well, at the very least now I know why I can't find the answer, haha.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't test it but I think something like this works:

```
select * from ((select name, sum(amount_paid) as 2009 from customer, payment
where customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
and payment.year = 2009) a,
(select name, sum(amount_paid) as 2008 from customer, payment
where customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
and payment.year = 2008) b
(select name, sum(amount_paid) as 2007 from customer, payment
where customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
and payment.year = 2007) c);
```